# What IP address is a Linux printer queue going to?

Tags: linux, printer, network-printer

I can get a list of printer queues with the lpstat command.  How can I examine these queues to find out the IP addresses of the printers that they are going to?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is simple:

```
lpstat -s
```